# Analysis tools UPDATE not available

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, basic-license-level

Why UPDATE from Analysis tools in ArcGIS 10.3.1 is not available to me, does it need some specific license or can it be download separately? How is it possible to achieve exactly the same result as with UPDATE without it?

[image]

[image: not available pic]

Comment: It requires Advanced License level. However, what exactly is it that you want to do? If just combine geometries, use the Merge or Append functions.

Comment: @Martin thank you, unfortunately do not have advanced licence. I think Merge function will help

Comment: Good, try that! :) Hint: See those locks on some functions? - I would guess that they show up on those you don't have license for.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will be able to do this using the Union tool, followed by the Select/Dissolve, using a Basic level license.  Just give Union a test and look at the attribute values you have to work with once that has run.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you very much! This combination is really what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update tool requires ArcGIS Advanced license. Check the bottom page of the [Update tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/update.htm) help. If you don't have ArcGIS advanced license, then it will be disabled.